# Azure AD Connect Installation Fails

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I keep getting `password does not meet the password policy requirement` while installing Azure AD Connector on a `2012R2Sserver` (*see error below*).

All domain password domain polices have been disabled.  Both local domain admin account and Azure accounts have complex passwords.  Any idea what is causing this error?

**Stack-trace error:**

> [23:18:12.297] [ 14] [INFO ] Starting Sync Engine installation
>   [23:18:17.265] [ 14] [ERROR] PerformConfigurationPageViewModel: Caught
>   exception while installing synchronization service. [23:18:17.265] [
>   13] [INFO ] Starting Telemetry Send Exception Data (Raw):
>   System.Exception: Unable to install the Synchronization Service. 
>   Please see the event log for additional details. --->
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PasswordException: The
>   password does not meet the password policy requirements. Check the
>   minimum password length, password complexity and password history
>   requirements.  ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: **The
>   password does not meet the password policy requirements. Check the
>   minimum password length, password complexity and password history
>   requirements.**    at
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.CommitChanges()    at
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SDSUtils.ApplyChangesToDirectory(Principal
>   p, StoreCtx storeCtx, GroupMembershipUpdater updateGroupMembership,
>   NetCred credentials, AuthenticationTypes authTypes)    --- End of
>   inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SDSUtils.ApplyChangesToDirectory(Principal
>   p, StoreCtx storeCtx, GroupMembershipUpdater updateGroupMembership,
>   NetCred credentials, AuthenticationTypes authTypes)    at
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SDSUtils.InsertPrincipal(Principal
>   p, StoreCtx storeCtx, GroupMembershipUpdater updateGroupMembership,
>   NetCred credentials, AuthenticationTypes authTypes, Boolean
>   needToSetPassword)    at
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SAMStoreCtx.Insert(Principal
>   p)    at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.Save()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.Framework.AccountManagementAdapter.CreatePrincipalCore(Principal
>   principal)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.Framework.AccountManagementAdapter.CreateUser(NetworkCredential
>   userCredential, String userDescription, Boolean
>   userPasswordNeverExpires)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.Setup.SynchronizationServiceSetupTask.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__2a()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.Framework.ActionExecutor.Execute(Action
>   action, String description)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.Setup.SynchronizationServiceSetupTask.CreateSyncServiceAccount(AccountManagementAdapter
>   accountManagementAdapter, String installationIdentifier)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.Setup.SynchronizationServiceSetupTask.InstallCore(String
>   logFilePath, String logFileSuffix)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.Framework.ActionExecutor.ExecuteWithSetupResultsStatus(SetupAction
>   action, String description, String logFileName, String logFileSuffix) 
>   at
>   Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.Setup.SetupBase.Install()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.Setup.SetupBase.ThrowSetupTaskFailureException(String
>   exceptionFormatString, String taskName, Exception innerException)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.Setup.SetupBase.Install()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Online.Deployment.OneADWizard.Providers.EngineSetupProvider.SetupSyncEngine(String
>   setupFilesPath, String installationPath, String sqlServerName, String
>   sqlInstanceName, String serviceAccountName, String
>   serviceAccountDomain, String serviceAccountPassword, String
>   groupAdmins, String groupBrowse, String groupOperators, String
>   groupPasswordSet, Int32 numberOfServiceInstances,
>   ProgressChangedEventHandler progressChanged, NetworkCredential&
>   serviceAccountCredential, SecurityIdentifier& serviceAccountSid)    at
>   Microsoft.Online.Deployment.OneADWizard.Runtime.Stages.InstallSyncEngineStage.ExecuteInstallCore(ISyncEngineInstallContext
>   syncEngineInstallContext, ProgressChangedEventHandler
>   progressChangesEventHandler)    at
>   Microsoft.Online.Deployment.OneADWizard.Runtime.Stages.InstallSyncEngineStage.ExecuteInstall(ISyncEngineInstallContext
>   syncEngineInstallContext, ProgressChangedEventHandler
>   progressChangesEventHandler)    at
>   Microsoft.Online.Deployment.OneADWizard.UI.WizardPages.PerformConfigurationPageViewModel.ExecuteSyncEngineInstallCore(AADConnectResult&
>   result)